# How to associate and populate models in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three models `Restaurant` `Menu` `Section`

Restaurant contains `id` `name`

Menu should only contain the `restaurantId` and that record's `id`

Section contains `id` `name` `menuId`

How do I associate the models, such that, I would have a resultant table like this

Restaurant

```
Id       Name
-----  ---------
 12       foo
 24       bar
```

Menu

```
    Id      restaurantId
   -----    ------------
     A          12
     B          24
```

Section

```
    Id        menuId        name
   -----    ------------   ------- 
     S1          A           Burgers
     S2          A           Sandwiches
     S3          B           Beverages
```

Answer (score 1):

create table : resturant

```
create table restaurant(
     r_id           serial primary key,
     r_name         varchar(32)
)
```

create table : menu

```
create table menu(
    r_id            serial references restaurant(r_id),
    m_id            serial primary key
)
```

create table: sect

```
create table sect(
    m_id        serial references menu(m_id),
    s_id        serial primary key,
    s_name      varchar(32)
)
```

now denife Sect model  :

```
  getSectModel(){
    return sequelizeObj.define('sect',{
        m_id:{
            type:               ORM.INTEGER,
            foreignKey:         true

        },
        s_id: {
            type:               ORM.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement:      true,
            primaryKey:         true
        },
        s_name: {
            type:               ORM.STRING
        }
    })
  }
```

same way define another 2 model of menu and resturant table then below query :

```
  enterDataInRestaurant(rname:string , sname:string[]){

      var sect = this.getSectModel();
      var menu = this.getMenuModel();
      var resturant = this.getRestaurantModel();

      // This below 2 line is for association 
      resturant.hasOne(menu, {foreignKey: 'r_id'})
      menu.hasMany(sect, {foreignKey: 'm_id'})

      resturant.create({
          r_name:    rname
          menu:{
                 sects:[
                         {s_name: sname[0]},
                         {s_nmae: sname[1]}
                       ]
               }
      },
      {
        include:[{
                model: menu,
                  include:[{
                      model:sect
                  }]
                }]

       }).then(function(result){
          console.log("results tag : "+result)
       }).catch(function(error){
          console.log("error",error)
       })
   }
```

now just call above method to enter data using association :

```
   enterDataInRestaurant('foo',['Burger','Sandwich']);
   enterDataInRestaurant('bar',['Beverages']);
```